# Axios Multiple Calls in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have Firebase real time data, Which has to be rendered on to the screen.

Im not well aware of redux, So thought of implementing it in Axios but in requirement of more than 7 GET functions.

Is it possible to do multiple axios calls? If so , Kindly help me out in the process of states, GET calls and response calls.

If you guys think redux and redux thunk must be used, Kindly suggest that methodology also to fetch data.

My default single axios call is as follows:

```
state = { toss: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonid-c22aa.firebaseio.com/tossdec.json')
      .then(response => this.setState({toss: response.data}));
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As ajax calls using `axios` return `Promise`, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to your benefit while handling multiple GET requests.

Comment: As im a newbie can you implement that promise function with a example

Comment: read the section *Performing multiple concurrent requests* section of [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) page. You just need to handle your requests in `componentWillMount` method as per the examples mentioned there

Comment: How do i set requests in axios then function and how to add extra state ! Im really stuck up now can you please implement and show